# What is the other local host server for sonar, since local 9000 is not working?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

What is the other local host server for sonar, since local 9000 is not working? Should the command prompt be running in the background while using the local host? Since whenever I try to open start sonar the command prompt automatically closes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try to open the command prompt and drag sonar exe to it and then run it? And also check if port 9000 is occupied somewhere to confirm?

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs if Java version being used is not Java 11. Therefore, do make sure that the installed java version is JAVA 11 only, as Sonarqube seems to have few compatibility issues when tried with other java versions.

How to download JAVA 11 ?

1. Download the zip from this [link](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/9/GPL/openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin.zip).
2. Say you have downloaded "openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin" in this location - "D:\openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin", then configure the following ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES with values mentioned below:

   a. ***JAVA_HOME*** - D:\openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin

   b. ***PATH*** - D:\openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin\jdk-11.0.2\bin

Once this is done, you can make sure JAVA 11 is installed and configured by entering **"java -version"** in the command prompt window